# Hylang "in" operator

Tags: hy

Is there an `in` operator in Hylang? In python, for example, this would allow for the following test:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(0 in lst)
# => False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and it has the same name:

```
=> (setv lst [1 2 3 4])
=> (in 0 lst)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Hylang seems to not have an operator that would check a list for occurences.

But there is a solution. You can use the `py` operator to check for list occurences via native python code.

It would look like that:

```py
(py "0 in lst")
```

Comment: Great answer! While I'll be sure to use this operator, according to the answers above, there is in fact an in operator: https://docs.hylang.org/en/alpha/api.html#hy.core.shadow.in

Answer (score 1):

(This would be better as a comment but my reputation doesn't suffice.)

The Hylang documentation includes a mention about the keyword `in`.

https://docs.hylang.org/en/alpha/api.html#hy.core.shadow.in

https://github.com/hylang/hy/blob/master/hy/pyops.hy#L126

Comment: Can you add comments to answers? Or neither questions nor answers? If so, I can accept Kodiologist's answer answer above with your answer as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70319387/10827766

Comment: Ah, that's okay.

Comment: Or should I add this as a comment to the accepted answer myself, giving credit to you?

Comment: Maybe it’s clear enough as it is.

Comment: If you insist! Thanks for the references anyway!